# Programmatic NPSP Lead Conversion

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, leads, lead-conversion, npsp

I have NPSP and a bunch of Leads whose 'Company' fields are filled with 'self' value. I'm using the Apex class which uses Database.LeadConvert to convert leads, but it creates an Organization 'self' instead of Households.
How can I use NPSP's lead conversion from apex, or flow when I want to convert some amount of Leads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NPSP methods are not global, so you can't call them from your own code.  There is a Callable_API class that is supposed to give access to a few NPSP methods, but it is incomplete and undocumented.  I've been able to get only one method to work (Data Import Batch scheduling).

See the [NPSP Github](https://github.com/SonarSource/apex-test-sources/blob/master/projects/Cumulus/src/classes/LD_LeadConvertOverride_CTRL.cls).

Also, the best resource for NPSP support is the [NPSP Trailblazer group](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F94S000000kHitSAE?tab=discussion&sort=LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_DESC)